# Transforming a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would appreciate a suggestion on the following : I am working with a `data.frame` (below) :

```
EXP    CT   row_names   col_names                 
1   test -5    B4:B5:B6    B1:B2:B3              
2   test -2    B7:B8:B9    B1:B2:B3              
3   test -2    D4:D5:D6    H4:H5:H6              
4   test -2    D10:D11:D12 F10:F11:F12             
5   test -2    D10:D11:D12    H1:H2:H3              
6   test -2    E10:E11:E12    G7:G8:G9             
7   test -4     A1:A2:A3    D1:D2:D3                
8   test -4   B10:B11:B12    B1:B2:B3
```

What would be the easiest way to consider UNIQUE elements in the `ROW_NAMES` or the UNIQUE elements in the `COL_NAMES` and print how many times these UNIQUE ELEMENTS associate with the numbers -5, -2, or -4? (These numbers are on the column named CT.)

Comment: If you're working with a "data.frame" per the title, you should tag the question with that and with R, but not with "dataframes".

Comment: If you are seeking an R solution, try `table(df1[2:3])` , `table(df1[c(2,4)])`